# Identify if the window opened is popup window or a normal window in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup

I have a requirement where i want to restrict users from opening url manually from browser. The url should only open from clicking a button which opens a pop window.

Notes:-1.) I cannot temper with button code that's application's standard code
2.) I have already tried window.opener but it does not work in IE.

So basically i want to identify if the opened window is a pop window or normal browser window.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot enforce such a restriction.

Comment: `window.opener` does work in IE (`undefined` if it's not a popup, or `object` if it is). Which IE have you tried it in?

Comment: IE 10. I know it use to work in previous versions of IE but it does not seem to work in this latest version of browser